# Do you know a lap timer that 'resets' each lap?

Tags: timing, app

One of the things that really motivates me when swimming, cycling or running is 'racing myself'.

However, all the lap timers I've found so far have the normal lap function of measuring the lap time, but not actually 'resetting' the clock each lap. So say I'm trying to keep on a 90 second turnaround and I make 83 seconds and press the lap button, then the clock continues on to 84, 85, 86 ... etc.

I'd like something that resets the clock each time I press the lap button so then I can **actually** see my current time versus my previous lap, versus having to mentally calculate it each time. This way I can pace myself more effectively and motivate myself to work harder if say I usually hit the halfway mark at 40 seconds, but I just did it in 43 for that lap.

Any sort of smartphone app or perhaps an actual stopwatch etc would be okay.

Comment: Doesn't a regular smartphone clock app have that feature?

Comment: It has something similar, but not quite exactly what I'm looking for. It records your lap time AND the overall time you were at when you pressed the lap button, but it doesn't reset the clock. So you could get the current time minus the recorded time from the previous lap, but sometimes that's a bit of an annoyance especially when I'm going max effort and want to think about nothing else but my progress for that lap.

Comment: Mine *(Android 4.4)* restarts the counter at the start of every lap. It also provides a grid of the number of laps covered as well as the duration of each lap. I simply start and stop the counter and I have access to all the information I need.

Answer (score 1):

I have two options for Android:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.dedmondson.timer.classiclite
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zabamobile.sportstimerfree

Both time resets after each lap as well of showing your total time.

Answer (score 1):

You should get a Timex Ironman watch:

[image: Timex Ironman watch]

Switch to the Chronometer (a fancy word for stopwatch) by pressing Mode. Start the stopwatch by pressing Start/Split, and stop it by pressing Stop/Reset. Reset the timer by pressing and holding Reset.

When the clock is running, you can press Start/Split to record a lap. For 10 seconds after you press Start/Split, your time for the last lap is displayed on the screen along with the lap number. Then, the timer switches to the time for your current lap and you can start all over again.

The Timex Ironman watch fits your purposes, but it's also a lot better than using an app on your phone or carrying a stopwatch. Do you really want to be mashing buttons on a $100+ smartphone with your sweaty hands each time you do a lap? I prefer to keep my phone clean, which is why I carry a watch. Every good runner I know has a GPS watch or a Timex Ironman watch, and the only time any of them have had to replace it is when they lost it. Mine has survived 5 years and almost 10,000 miles of easy runs, workouts, strength training, etc. I highly recommend it - it's both extremely functional and practically indestructible.